# Share version information in Azure DevOps

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, azure-devops, release

I've written a small Android application using Xamarin Android. As the title suggests, I'm using Azure DevOps as CI and Release pipeline. The finally signed APK is published as a GitHub release.

Now I'd like to centralize the version information. At the moment, the Android version information in `AndroidManifest.xml` and GitHub release version are independent and I have to synchronize them manually.

How can I do this? Obviously, I could do something like:

1. Centralize version information within a single file
2. Read file as a build step in Azure DevOps
3. Pass the extracted information into the Xamarin build step and the GitHub release step.

Is there any built-in approach that comes without this manual ceremony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about a built-in way but there is [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks) (Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android) for Azure DevOps which provides a 'Bump Version' function. There is a blog post and video about it [here](https://montemagno.com/enhanced-mobile-app-versioning-in-azure-devops-vsts-with-mobile-tasks/).